# stack trace problem in eclipse

Tags: java, android, exception

I wrote a code as shown below to print stack trace. I am using eclipse IDE. I am unable to view the stack trace. I checked in console and logcat.

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
    //Exception handling
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("error in uploading", ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: probably u might not be getting any exception. ;). N-Joy.

Comment: Log.e("error in uploading"+ex.getMessage(), ex);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logcat exception stack traces with...

```
catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "IOException: " + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is multiple devices showing in your DDMS=>Devices tab? If this is the case then select the device you are running your application. LogCat shows logging from one device at a time